# RegExp in Node Js not working: Cannot call method 'toString' of null

Tags: regex, node.js

This exact function does not work on Node Js, even though it work fine on a regular browser. How can I make it work on NodeJS?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wC53N/

```
var MyHereDoc = function() {
    var bodyEmail = function(){
        var test = 1;
/*HEREDOC
<div>
    Hola1
    <p>
       hola2
    </p>
</div>
HEREDOC*/
    };

    var here = "HEREDOC";
    var reobj = new RegExp("/\\*"+here+"\\n[\\s\\S]*?\\n"+here+"\\*/", "m");
    str = reobj.exec(bodyEmail).toString();
    str = str.replace(new RegExp("/\\*"+here+"\\n",'m'),'').toString();
    toPrint =  str.replace(new RegExp("\\n"+here+"\\*/",'m'),'').toString();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = toPrint;
}
MyHereDoc();
```

If you try to run this same code on NodeJS u will get this error:

```
Cannot call method 'toString' of null
```

But Why? any idea how to make it works, or what am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Works for me, after replacing document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = toPrint; 
with 
console.log(toPrint); 
I'm on 0.10.26 right now

Comment: ok thanks!... I will check my NodeJS version then, maybe is that.